# How to force re-render a React function component

Tags: reactjs

so I want to be able to force re-render `<UpdateModal>` every time clicked on a row.
and every time clicked on a row,  get clicked row's data to the modal.

Since I'm new to react, I'm using Normal bootstrap to open the modal.

```
import React from 'react'
  const [selectedRow, setSelectedRow] = useState({});

  const selectRow = (row) => {
    setSelectedRow(row);
  };

const Table = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <table>
                 <thead>
                  <tr>hello</tr>
                 </thead>
                 <tbody>
                 <tr data-mdb-toggle="modal" data-mdb-target="#updateModal" onClick={() => selectRow(row)}>
                   <td> hello1 </td>
                 </tr>
                 <tr data-mdb-toggle="modal" data-mdb-target="#updateModal" onClick={() => selectRow(row)}>
                   <td> hello2 </td>
                 </tr>
                 <tr data-mdb-toggle="modal" data-mdb-target="#updateModal" onClick={() => selectRow(row)}>
                   <td> hello3 </td>
                 </tr>
                </tbody>
           </table>
         {selectedRow && <UpdateModal selectedRow={selectedRow} />}
        </div>

    )
}

export default Table
```

Comment: If it doesn't do any state change, what is the reason to re-render `UpdateModal` ? Because `selectedRow` won't be changed anymore !?

Comment: When you are clicking on a row, its triggering the `onClick` function but in that function you are giving row as a parameter `selectRow(row)` but you haven't defined row at all. Please give some worthwile value to that row and then the useState hook will be updated which will re-render the component

Comment: @jainChetan81 sorry I didnt post all of code . this is simplified . ```onClick``` get the row data set and set it to selectedRow . I can confirm that every time open the modal it has that value. problem is that , if i change any values on modal .  It will stay same even if I open another row..

Comment: When you are changing values on the modal, are you updating the `selectRow` state as well? because otherwise re-rendering would not occur

Comment: No . is that means save modal data to the table ? I dont do that yet